# Work with spread.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I'm new in using spread .net for fetch the data, so i have little knowledge about it, here my task is

```
1. How we check any row is selected or not
2. How we convert number in amount format
```

Comment: More information needed.

Comment: if Spread.net means farpoint spread .net ah? you mean selected means active row ah?

Comment: no i have no idea about .net spreadsheet @KayNelson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1. check selection use `FpSpread1.ActiveSheetView.ActiveRow`
2. `Currency Cell type` **(Dim x As FarPoint.Web.Spread.CurrencyCellType = New FarPoint.Web.Spread.CurrencyCellType)**

Comment: thanks it work for me.. can you also tell me where i found .net spread documentation...

Comment: Try this [http://www2.fpoint.com/FarPointSupportSite/Modules/Docs/] ,